# Sometimes font looks strange in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

See **Edit** below

**Edit2** I created a fiddle to reproduce the problem and as it seems in jsfiddle the problem is allways there: https://jsfiddle.net/h1b2wn5L/ (just in chrome)

Sometimes the font I use for a webproject looks strange. The font is called `Istok Web` and I load it from google fonts: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Istok+Web

I created 2 pictures. One with the problem:
[image]

And one after a simple reload of the page:
[image]

As you can see the `T`and `E` have like a bold top and in a normal Text `T` and `E` stands out.

I have no clue where this is coming from and its also gone after a simple reload. What could it be? I also can't say if this also happens in other browsers or not, as I work with crome and I don't know how to reproduce the problem.

**Edit** I found out how to reproduce the problem. The problem comes when I switch to mobile view in the Developer Tools. And it stays when I switch back to normal view. So I guess its not a big problem, but I am curious why this happens.

Comment: I had weird errors with this if there was something using translate3d anywhere on the page.

Comment: @Blowski I had this too before and it was a problem with a graphic card driver. But in this case I do not use translate3d and I also cant reproduce the problem. It is just sometimes there and after a reload its gone

Comment: So, without some code to reproduce the problem, everyone's going to be guessing, as seen in existing answers. If you can make a [mcve], others can more easily help you.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I added a fiddle. I do not even need to open the developer tools to see the problem in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to aliasing problems. 
You can use some alternatives for webkit browsers using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` but you won't be able to reproduce this fix in Firefox.

You could go for a workaround using text-shadow, as described here: https://www.elfboy.com/blog/text-shadow_anti-aliasing/

Comment: Same here, I had the problem again and tested this, it did not help. I also tried text-shadow (it looks a bit better, but the problem is still the same and I have no clue why it only happens every 100. time)

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers do caching most of the time (and web servers, depending on its configurations), When you refreshed the page it reloaded page resources and brought the correct font from google. Also, maybe the font was not loaded perfectly in the first time.

However some fonts do look bad in some browsers, and pay attention to font size some work better in even numbers and some in odd numbers (e.g. 13px vs 12px). Make experiments then choose.

you can try the following CSS rules to enhance the font as well (no guarantee to work, but makes no harm):

```
html {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale !important;
}
```

Comment: I had the problem again and tested this, did not help. Reload the page and problem is gone (also before I did not a hard reload or something, very strange)

Comment: I saw your fiddle, you are using font-size = 15px; when I tried 16px it was much better. I think that's the issue, notice how letters looks different when you change to 16 or 14. at 15 its stretched vertically and lose quality.